# Jade (1.0+) template error in Node.js Express app: 'Duplicate key "id" is not allowed.'

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, express, pug

Thanks for any advice on this:

In my [Express app](https://github.com/rfcx/rfcx-api-express), I'm passing several parameters into a Jade template, which now generates this fatal error:

`Duplicate key "id" is not allowed.`

(from what I can gather, I am not passing any parameter with index "id" into the template)

The app works fine with Jade 0.32.0, but breaks with any version 1.0+.

Here is the code where I construct the parameter array (function: `setJadeVars`, line 29) and then pass that array into the jade template (line 63):

https://github.com/rfcx/rfcx-api-express/blob/master/routes/index.js

The error doesn't seem to be related to passing the parameters into the template, because the error only occurs when I try to use the parameters (ie, if I pass the parameters in, but don't invoke them anywhere, the rendering occurs just fine).

If it helps, here is a console.log dump of the object I'm passing into the template:

```
{ current_page: 
   [ 'about',
     'About',
     '/about',
     'Rainforest Connection | About',
     true,
     false ],
  app_version: '832292378e7a',
  node_env: 'development',
  title: 'Title (development)',
  segment_io_client_id: 'wimr8bjvcr',
  addthis_pubid: 'ra-xxx',
  bootstrap_cdn: '/vendor',
  googlelibs_cdn: '/vendor',
  videojs_cdn: '/vendor/video.js',
  cdnjs_cdn: '/vendor',
  rfcx_cdn: '/cdn',
  rfcx_vendor_cdn: '/vendor',
  rfcx_static_cdn: '//x-static.s3.amazonaws.com',
  nav_items: 
   [ [ 'intro',
       'Home',
       '/',
       'Rainforest Connection | Protecting rainforests with real-time data',
       true,
       false ],
     [ 'about',
       'About',
       '/about',
       'Rainforest Connection | About',
       true,
       false ],
     [ 'get_involved',
       'Get Involved',
       '/get_involved',
       'Rainforest Connection | Get Involved',
       true,
       false ],
     [ 'blog',
       'Blog',
       '/blog',
       'Rainforest Connection | Blog',
       false,
       false ],
     [ 'team',
       'Team',
       '/team',
       'Rainforest Connection | Team',
       false,
       false ],
     [ 'tumblr',
       'Tumblr',
       'http://tumblr.rfcx.org/',
       'Rainforest Connection | ',
       true,
       false ],
     [ 'video',
       null,
       '/video',
       'Rainforest Connection | Rainforest Connection | Protecting rainforests with real-time data',
       false,
       true,
       {} ] ],
  social_media: 
   [ [ 'github',
       '[link redacted for stack-overflow]',
       'github-square',
       'Fork our repos on Github!' ],
     [ 'instagram',
       '[link redacted for stack-overflow]',
       'instagram',
       'Check us out on Instagram!' ],
     [ 'flickr',
       'http://flickr.com/photos/rainforestcx/',
       'flickr',
       'Check us out on Flickr!' ],
     [ 'linkedin',
       '[link redacted for stack-overflow]',
       'linkedin-square',
       'Check us out on LinkedIn!' ],
     [ 'google-plus',
       '[link redacted for stack-overflow]',
       'google-plus-square',
       'Check us out on Google+!' ],
     [ 'twitter',
       '[link redacted for stack-overflow]',
       'twitter-square',
       'Check us out on Twitter!' ],
     [ 'facebook',
       '[link redacted for stack-overflow]',
       'facebook-square',
       'Check us out on Facebook!' ] ]
}
```

Any ideas on what could be causing the error would be deeply appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Could you also provide a .jade template where it breaks ?

Comment: i think, that it isn't a problem with that object, you would see a object key with ID which would hold the latest `id` value, instead there is none, can also post the line where the `jade` `res.render` is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is caused by code like this:

```
span#foo#bar
```

Or this:

```
span#foo(id='bar')
```

Note two id tags. I recently encounter this too. If you can't find it, show the offending jade template, and I can point at it.

Comment: I'm the poster of the original question. This answer solved the problem. Thanks for the concise answer! Awesome!